# Calculate next trigger time from crontab-like string

Tags: go, cron

Is there a method, in Go, to calculate simply next execution time from a crontab-like string?

For example, the input is:

```
*/5 * * * *
```

And the output should be, at the moment that i'm writing:

2021-04-21 17:55:00

An illustrative example can be viewed here:

```
https://crontab.guru/#*/5_*_*_*_*
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is something in the standard library? If so, then no I don't think there is. You might need a third-party library or to write your own parser. This looks like it could be a starting point https://github.com/robfig/cron

Comment: You've described the requirements, what have you tried? Please share your code.

Comment: Perhaps i found what i was looking for: https://github.com/gorhill/cronexpr

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution with the external library github.com/gorhill/cronexpr:

```
import "github.com/gorhill/cronexpr"
import "time"

nextTime := cronexpr.MustParse("*/10 * * * *").Next(time.Now())
```

The output will be, at this moment:

```
"2021-04-22 14:50:00"
```